# Restrict anonymous users to view other tabs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3. As of now I am restricting anonymous users to enter a particular page through

```
[Authorize]
```

in my controller. But what I want is to restrict them to view a tab in the main page if they are not log.in. Is this possible.? Sorry Im not pro in programming. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah obcourse. You can do something like this

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("View Account", "Index", "Account")</li>
    if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin Console", "Index", "Admin")</li>
    }
}
```

**reference:[Checking authentication and roles in a view](http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx)**

Comment: If lets say I dont have a role is it ok to remove the if(User.IsInRole("Administrator"))?

Comment: yes.. Just include the @if(Request.IsAuthenticated) in your _Layout